# Works in JSFiddle, not browser even when placed in document ready handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on printing out a 16x16 grid of divs using jQuery. I managed to get it to print correctly on JSFiddle; however, when testing it in the browser only one row is printed. I noticed when I change the extension on JSFiddle from jQuery (edge) to jQuery 2.1.3 the I receive the same result as if I put it in the browser. What is causing this?

I understand that similar questions have been asked before, but I have looked through a ton of different questions like mine that gave answers that weren't able to help me. Each answer I found said to use window.onload = function () {}, $(document).ready(function () {}), replace $ with jQuery, or change where I link the javascript. I tried all four of those with no avail. Perhaps I missed one that answered me. Hopefully someone can let me know where in my code I am going wrong, or post a link to another question that has an answer.

jQuery

```
$square = $('<td><div class = "square"></div></td>');

$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= 16; j++) {
            $("#contain").append("<td></td>");
        }
        $("#contain").append("<tr></tr>");

    }
    $square.appendTo("td");
});
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Game</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="gamecss.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="gamejs.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id = "contain"></table>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#contain
{
    width:100%;
}
.square
{
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    border: solid 1px black;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: What is the issue again? Is that the bug in JavaScript code OR you want it to run on your Computer, rather than Fiddle.

Comment: The issue is that it works when in Fiddle but not when run in the browser. I would very much like it to work in the browser.

Comment: You're appending `td` elements directly to a `table`? What were you hoping the result would be? It doesn't really make sense to do that. Did you mean to append them to the new, empty `tr` element you created? Where's the jsFiddle where this works?

Comment: ...and then you're appending a `td` to a `td`. None of this really makes any sense WRT the semantics of your elements. I just tried this in jsFiddle and it doesn't create 16 rows.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the js to append (col) `td` to the last (row) `tr` of (table) `contain`.

```js
$square = $('<td><div class = "square"></div></td>');
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= 16; j++) {
            $("#contain tr").last().append("<td></td>");
        }
        $("#contain").append("<tr></tr>");

    }
    
    $square.appendTo("td");
});
```

```css
#contain
{
    width:100%;
}
.square
{
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    border: solid 1px black;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <body>
        <table id = "contain"></table>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try adding your JS code in body within `<script>....JS Code...</script>` tags.

**HTML File**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Game</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="gamecss.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="gamejs.js"></script>
        <style>
        #contain
        {
            width:100%;
        }
        .square
        {
            height: 20px;
            width: 20px;
            background-color: black;
            border: solid 1px black;
            display: block;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id = "contain"></table>

        <script>
        $square = $('<td><div class = "square"></div></td>');
        $(document).ready(function () {
            for (var i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
                for (var j = 1; j <= 16; j++) {
                    $("#contain").append("<td></td>");
                }
                $("#contain").append("<tr></tr>");

            }
            $square.appendTo("td");
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Just copy above code and create a html file of it, run it and you will have what you want.